# neo4jrestclient , to add property after node is created

Tags: python, nosql, neo4j

I am trying to create new node , but when i add extra property in next line it fails .
For eg :

```
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
index = gdb.nodes.indexes.create('blogger')
for i in b:
  uid = gdb.nodes.create(user_id=x,gender=i[0],profile_views=i[1],industry=i[2],occupation=i[3],email=i[4],locality=i[5],country=i[6],region=i[7])
# till here it adds all the properties as mentioned
# following 2 lines of code fails
uid.setProperty('hosts',<value>)
uid.relationships.create("follows",<value>)
```

One more query : **How can we add relationship between property of a node to the property of another node**

for eg: in above relationship i want to create relationship between host which are unique to each node

Comment: i got a feeling that you must first commit the create query. at least in other frameworks there is a line of code like `gdb.finish();` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the author, @versae it is

In neo4j-rest-client the syntax is just

```
uid.set('hosts',<value>)
```

Or

```
uid['hosts'] = <value>
```

see: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/YbIKeHh4lCw/Grj8nRx7UdAJ

Comment: not working , it just adds properties as present in the first line and does not retain the changes for the next line , will try it again , thanks for help